# scipy.signal.wiener filter noise variance

Tags: python, signal-processing, wiener-filter

Just wanted to understand how the wiener filter works.

I was looking at https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/wiener2.html, and read "The Wiener filter tailors itself to the local image variance. Where the variance is large, wiener2 performs little smoothing. Where the variance is small, wiener2 performs more smoothing."
I would assume that where the noise variance is large, the wiener2 would perform more smoothing to remove the noise. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Also, is there another way to calculate the noise parameter, since they allow one to input their own value in the wiener function? Say you had a signal to noise ratio, how would you specify that as an input?

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: How is this not about programming lol? The wiener filter is widely used in DSP, and python has a function for it. Edit: I've changed the title to scipy.signal.wiener to make it clearer.